# Opening images with OpenCV 2.4.11 to use as a dataset for sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm currently working with the following:

- Python 2.7
- OpenCV 2.4.11
- Sklearn 0.16.1

and am using the [following tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html).

---

My goal is to load my own dataset instead of using a predefined dataset. I'm trying to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
  
digits = datasets.load_digits()

imageFolderPath ='C:/PathToFolderContainingMyImages/'

# Getting all the paths for each image
individualImagePaths = [ imageFolderPath + f for f in listdir(imageFolderPath) if isfile(join(imageFolderPath,f))]
individualImagePaths = sorted(individualImagePaths)

logos = []
logoLabels = []

for x in individualImagePaths:
    filename = os.path.basename(x).split(" ")
    filename = filename[0]

    logos.append(np.array(cv2.imread(x,0)))
    logoLabels.append(filename)

logos = np.asarray(logos)
logoLabels = np.asarray(logoLabels)

print type(logos)
print type(logoLabels)
print logos[0]
print logoLabels[0]

print type(digits.images)
print type(digits.target)
print digits.images[0]
print digits.target[0]

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(logos[:-1], logoLabels[:-1])
```

I'm getting the following error when running this script:

```
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

My images are named:

> "1 (1).png" for a image that is of a 1 digit
>
> "2 (1).png" for a image that is of a 2 digit
>
> "2 (2).png" for a image that is of a 2 digit

---

```
print type(logos)
print type(logoLabels)
print logos[0]
print logoLabels[0]
```

returns:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]]
0
```

---

```
print type(digits.images)
print type(digits.target)
print digits.images[0]
print digits.target[0]
```

returns:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[  0.   0.   5.  13.   9.   1.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  13.  15.  10.  15.   5.   0.]
 [  0.   3.  15.   2.   0.  11.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  12.   0.   0.   8.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   5.   8.   0.   0.   9.   8.   0.]
 [  0.   4.  11.   0.   1.  12.   7.   0.]
 [  0.   2.  14.   5.  10.  12.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   6.  13.  10.   0.   0.   0.]]
0
```

Any ideas on how I can create/load my owndata set and use the dataset with the sklearn `fit` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else looks at this and is having trouble, I've worked backwards and saved the digit dataset into individual images, reloaded the images, trained my classifier, and then predicted the image.

I ended up not using opencv as seen in the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
import uuid
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def scipySaveImage(path,name,image):
    scipy.misc.imsave(path + name,image)

def scipyLoadImage(path,flatten=0):
        return scipy.misc.imread(path,flatten)

def saveAsUniqueImage(path,image,target):
        # Defining our parts
        target = str(target)
        unique = str(uuid.uuid1())
        extension = '.png'
        name = target + '-' + unique + extension
        scipySaveImage(path,name,image)

def saveDataSet(path,dataset):
    for i,image in enumerate(dataset.images):
        target = dataset.target[i]
        saveAsUniqueImage(path,image,target)

def predict(classifier,data):
        return classifier.predict(data[:len(data)])

def shape_data(data):
        n_samples = len(data)
        return data.reshape((n_samples, -1))

def train_classifer(data):
        n_samples = len(data)
        data = shape_data(data)
        classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
        classifier.fit(data[:n_samples], digits.target[:n_samples])
        return classifier

# A Dataset Object
class dataset:
        def __init_():
                return

def loadTestDataset(path):
        data = dataset()
        targets = []
        filenames = []
        images = []

        imagePaths = [ path + f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path,f))]
        imagePaths = sorted(imagePaths)

        for x in imagePaths:
                filename = os.path.basename(x)
                target = filename.split("-")
                target = target[0]
                target = int(target)

                targets.append(target)
                filenames.append(filename)
                images.append(scipy.misc.imread(x,1))

        data.target = np.asarray(targets)
        data.images = np.asarray(images)
        data.filenames = filenames

        return data

# The folder where my digit images will go in
training_path = 'Digits/'

# Saving the images in the digit dataset into the Digit folder
# Comment out this line if you already have the digits
saveDataSet(training_path,datasets.load_digits())

# Loading all the images from a folder into a dataset
digits = loadTestDataset(training_path)

# Reloads the images from our training folder
test_digits = loadTestDataset(training_path)

# Shaping the images, I believe this just makes the rows 1 pixel so an 8x8 image will now be 64x1
test_digits.images = shape_data(test_digits.images)

# Training our classifer so it knows how to classify digits
digits_model = train_classifer(digits.images)

# The target that our model thinks is being represented
prediction = predict(digits_model,test_digits.images[300])

# Printing the filename ( which includes the target ) and our models prediction
print test_digits.filenames[300]
print prediction
```